# How to calculate the overlapping rate between two columns and plot a pivot table to plot the heatmap (Python)?

Tags: python, for-loop, seaborn

I have two columns like

```
data= {'country':['China', 'China', 'France', 'Italy', 'France'], 'domain': ['abc.com', 'def.com', 'abc.com', 'fga.com', 'exo.com']}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
```

How to calculate the overlapping rate (group by countries and calculate the domain count in each country)? It is expected to generate a pivot table to plot a heat map so that we can see the overlapping between each country.

In this example, the overlapping between China and France has 1 overlapping domain, which is the abc.com, and the total universe set between the two countries is 3 (abc.com, def.com and exo.com). So the overlapping rate between the two countries is 1/3. It is asked to calculate all overlapping rate across all countries.

```
cn= ['abc.com', 'def.com']
fr= ['abc.com', 'def.com', 'exo.com']
setA = set(cn)
setB = set(fr)

overlap = setA & setB
universe = setA | setB
result = float(len(overlap)) / len(universe)
```

There are thousands of domains and about 15 countries. Therefore, it is more efficiently to use some for loop which I am not good at.

Thank you.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a homework service. Better spend some more time studying for loops. Or as it seems you are also using pandas. There are also numerous tutorials explaining how to achieve this using pandas.

Comment: Thank you Hielka. I have solved problem by typing all the steps by hands. Still a long way to go to get it fully automated.